# Проверить два трехмерных вектора на коллинеарность через пропорции

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

**Задача:** захотелось найти способ проверки двух трехмерных вектора на коллинеарность *требующий меньше вычислений чем проверка через векторное произведение векторов*.

**Как я пытался решить задачу:** я рассуждал следующим образом - если два вектора A и B коллинеарны, то они линейно зависимы. Это значит, что умножив вектор A на некоторое число Q я получу вектор B. В координатной форме это выглядит так - `A = (Bx*Q, By*Q, Bz*Q)`. Отсюда получаем пропорцию - `Ax/Bx = Ay/By = Az/Bz`. Переносим все в одну сторону и получаем Ax/Bx - Ay/By - Az/Bz = 0. Деление - это плохо, т.к. может возникнуть деление на ноль, поэтому избавимся от него умножив обе части равенства на `Bx*By*Bz`. Получим итоговую формулу - `Ax*By*Bz - Ay*Bx*Bz - Az*Bx*By = 0`.

**В чем проблема:** не работает) например для случая A(100, 0, 100) и B(0, 100, 0). Пожалуйста, скажите - где я допустил ошибку и в чем она заключается.

Comment: Вы по сути говорите, что из 2 - 1 - 1 == 0 следует, что 2 == 1 == 1... Из того, что из А следует Б, не следует, что из Б следует А :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для тройного равенства нельзя всё переносить в одну сторону, нужно рассматривать два отдельных равенства, иначе, как в приведённом примере, ненулевые разности могут взаимоуничтожаться

```
Ax/Bx = Ay/By = Az/Bz

if (Ax*By == Ay*Bx) && (Ay*Bz == Az*By)
   коллинеарны
(Ax/Bx с Az/Bz уже можно не сравнивать, т.к. два равенства 
 подразумевают третье (транзитивность))
```

Фактически в этом способе вычисляются два из трёх компонентов векторного произведения.

P.S. См. замечание @sercxj в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо, @MBo. Могли бы вы сказать - как из тройного равенства получить двойное.

Comment: @MBo Предположим Ay = By = 0. Очевидно, это условие недостаточно, чтобы считать трёхмерные векторы коллинеарными, однако первый вариант вашей проверки будет утверждать, что они коллинеарны.

Comment: @sercxj Да, есть такой неприятный момент - видимо, приведёт к необходимости ещё одного сравнения.

Comment: @MBo Второй способ так же недостаточен. Рассмотрим векторы A(0, 0, 1) и B(2, 1, 0). По вашему алгоритму PerpB = (-1, 2, 0). Его скалярное произведение с A равно нулю, однако A и B не коллинеарны.

Comment: @sercxjo Мда, перенос двумерных привычек на 3D не всегда приводит к верным выводам... Здесь я пошёл от коллинеарности, получив необходимое условие, но не достаточное.